Umbraco V15 - Mess my home page - weird issue with getting nodes from tree
In my home page I'm taking the latest nodes in the tree for each section.
My website is a news site.
So for example, my tree looks something like:
Magazine

 Category 1
    2013
       news item
       news item
    2014
    ..
    2023
    2024
       news item
       news item

 Category 2
 .
 .
 Category 3
 etc.

So every time I'm adding a new item, it will automatically shows in home page for each section - like, the latest news.
The code looks something like:
category_3_node = Umbraco.Content(1234);     
var category_3_pagesToList = @category_3_node.Children.Where(n => n.IsVisible());
category_3_pagesToList = category_3_node.DescendantsOrSelf().Where(n => n.ContentType.Alias == "NewsPage");

Where 1234 is the node id for the specific category (each category obviously has different id) in the tree which under I have folders for each year, then the news items.
Until now U9 - U14 it worked well.
Now after upgrading to U15 this code doesn't show the correct node. When I add a new item it doesn't shows the right item - means, it doesn't show the newest item. It suddenly shows items from 2015 for example.
If I want to get the latest one, I need to put for each category the ID of 2024.
But I don't want to do it, because , like what - now every year I'll have to update manually the code with the new id for the year ??
Until now I didn't have to do it
What have been changed in U15 that it messed my website?
And how to fix it.
Thanks
P.S.
Just noticed that I can't find the node id (1234) anymore in the back office, it rather shows the guid. should I switch in the code (regardless of the issue) to Guid.Parse(" instead of id ?
(my website started with version ~4 so still using id)
